# AWS - Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I'm learning about AWS networking and there's something I cannot understand.

If a security group has an outbound rule with these configs :
Destination : 0.0.0.0/0 -
Type : All Trafic

why can't it reach the Internet without an Internet Gateway? it already has a rule that allows all traffic to go outside

My instances in that security group are able to access the internet only with an Internet Gateway.

Comment: The Internet Gateway is the actual connection to the Internet. You can think of it like the cable modem in your home. If that wasn't there, you could allow access to the Internet in your laptop's firewall all you wanted to, but it wouldn't be able to access the Internet without the actual connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security group is more or less like a firewall. It acts as a kind of gate keeper in what ingress and egress traffic is allowed.

It doesn't do anything with the actual transport of the request to its destination.

If you look at the routing table (not the security group), you'll see that for outbound internet access, the `0.0.0.0/0` is routed to the IGW.

Comment: The security group dictates what type of traffic is allowed. It doesn't deal with the actual routing of the traffic. In your example, by default, security groups allow all egress traffic. So your EC2 instance wants to hit the internet -> security group allows it -> route table shows a path to the internet gateway

Comment: I think OP is essentially asking what an internet gateway is

Comment: Thanks @alex067, I have a better understanding now!